# Calculating a simple limit in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

So, I was working on this exercise that required me to prove a certain
function from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $0^{[k]}$.
By simply using the infamous triangle inequality I reached the conclusion
that the function (denote by $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) is bounded by the following:
\begin{gather*}
    \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^k \\
    \begin{cases}
        -\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} |x_i|^{5}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_i^4} & x \neq 0 \\
        0 & x = 0
    \end{cases} \leq f(x) \leq 
    \begin{cases}
        \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} |x_i|^{5}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_i^4} & x \neq 0 \\
        0 & x = 0
    \end{cases}
\end{gather*}

So define:
\begin{gather*}
    g: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
    (x_1, \; ... \, , \: x_k) \rightarrow  
    \begin{cases}
        \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} |x_i|^{5}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_i^4} & x \neq 0 \\
        0 & x = 0
    \end{cases} 
\end{gather*}
Thus, if I prove $g(x) \xrightarrow[x \rightarrow 0^{[k]}]{} 0$ I can apply the sandwich rule and the proof is setteled.
The thing is, I know this limit is true, it must be so. I think it is trivial, but I simply can't find the right direction.
I feel as if there is some sort of an algebraic trick I am missing or something.

Any hint or comments would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit:

The original function:
\begin{gather*}
f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
(x_1, \; ... \, , \: x_k) \rightarrow
    \begin{cases}
        \dfrac{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} (-1)^i \cdot x_i^{2021} }{ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_i^{2020} } & x \neq 0 \\
        0 & x = 0
    \end{cases}
\end{gather*}
(I changed the powers for simplification purposes)

Thank you so much, have a great weekend.

Comment: What is the original function $f$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}|x_i|^{5} \leq (\max \{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_k|\} )\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}|x_i|^{4}$. Can you finish?

Comment: Oh yes, I think I can. So using another sandwich in this case is the idea, and then it turns into the most simple case. *sigh* I am starting to think my future in math is not too bright. Not willing to give up though. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself. Sometimes we miss some simple arguments.  @GamowDrop